# MYSQL Multiple Selects, Where and Group By for Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MYSQL queries that i am trying to merge into one, here is the first one -

```
SELECT 
  `Your_Name` as agentname,
  sum(`Sale_Amount`) as todaysales, 
  COUNT(*) as NoSales 
FROM mp_wp_sales_tracking 
WHERE `created` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND NOW() 
GROUP BY agentname
```

And the second one is the same query, just for the previous day

```
SELECT 
  `Your_Name` as agentname,
  sum(`Sale_Amount`) as yesterdaysales, 
  COUNT(*) as YesterdayNoSales 
FROM mp_wp_sales_tracking 
WHERE `created` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                    AND ADDTIME(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'23:59:59.50') 
GROUP BY agentname
```

Now what i am trying to do, is achieve something like below (Headers as per aliases in MYSQL)

```
| agentname | todaysales | nosales | yesterdaysales | yesterdaynosales |
```

I have already tried to use Inner Join, but keep getting SQL errors, i am not sure where to turn on this, being quite new to complex MYSQL queries.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of one way to merge these 2 queries and use conditional aggregation for the results

```
SELECT `Your_Name` as agentname,
SUM( CASE WHEN 
    `created` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND ADDTIME(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'23:59:59.50') 
    THEN `Sale_Amount`
    ELSE 0 END
    ) as yesterdaysales,
SUM(`created` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND ADDTIME(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'23:59:59.50') ) as YesterdayNoSales ,
SUM(CASE WHEN 
    `created` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND NOW()
    THEN `Sale_Amount`
    ELSE 0 END
    ) as todaysales,
SUM(`created` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND NOW() ) as NoSales
FROM mp_wp_sales_tracking 
WHERE `created` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND ADDTIME(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'23:59:59.50') 
       OR `created` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND NOW() 
GROUP BY agentname
```

Comment: But it's so much query. How tedious :-(

Comment: Worked perfectly first time, and now ive seen the query, it actually makes sense where i was going wrong. Thankyou, youve saved me a huge headache !

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation (i.e. boolean expressions inside an aggragtion function such as `SUM`).

```
select 
  your_name as agentname,
  sum(case when date(created) = curdate() then sale_amount end) as todaysales, 
  sum(date(created) = curdate()) as todaynosales,
  sum(case when date(created) = curdate() - interval 1 day then sale_amount end)
    as yesterdaysales, 
  sum(date(created) = curdate() - interval 1 day) as yesterdaynosales
from mp_wp_sales_tracking 
where created >= curdate() - interval 1 day
group by agentname
order by agentname;
```